# How to override UITableView's function?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to do something on `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {...}` so that every `UITableView` will run this override function.

How can I do that? Can I do that by extension or subclass?

I am new for programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollViewDidScroll` is a delegate method of `UIScrollViewDelegate` and `UITableView` is inherited from `UIScrollView` . This can't be achieved with extension or subclassing UITableView, because it's a delegate method.

You can override this function in your `UITableView` delegate class only.

If you are using `UIViewController`s. Create a base class `BaseViewController`

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }
}
```

If you are using `UITableViewController`s, Create a base class `BaseTableViewController`

```
class BaseTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    public override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }
}
```

Now just change all your controllers super class to `BaseViewController` or `BaseTableViewController`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but i think u get me wrong. for example, i have several uiviewcontroller and each one has one tableview. I don't want to override the method in each tableview. i just want to override once and apply to all tableview

Comment: hmmm... This can't be achieved with extension or subclassing `UITableView`, because it's a delegate method.

If all your `UITableView` delegates are `UIViewController` you can subclass `UIViewController` lets say `BaseViewController` and override `scrollViewDidScroll` in base `BaseViewController. Now you just have to change all your `UIViewController`'s inherit from `BaseViewController`

Comment: I have to initialise uitableview on baseviewcontroller? seems a little bit complicated. Could you mind provide some example of code? thank you so much,